# How does kubelet inform about SIGTERM signal to kubernetes node?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

We have container per pod. Each container runs a service that listens on SIGTERM signal to initiate it's shutdown process.

To initiate the shutdown process,

1. does `kubectl delete pod [podname]` command needs to be initiated?
2. does container receive the SIGTERM signal from the linux kernel of the kubernetes node?
3. if yes, how does kubelet inform the kernel of kubernetes node, to throw SIGTERM signal on a specific container?

Note: of course pod is just a network namespace isolated container

Comment: This is described in detail in [Pod Lifecycle](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) in the Kubernetes documentation.  Short answers: yes; yes; using kill(2).

Comment: @DavidMaze now I got it, how kubelet sends signal..

Comment: @tmarveen Does `kubelet apply` command also initiate the container runtime to send a `SIGTERM` signal?

Comment: It should as per the `kubectl apply` command specification. If the configuration update affects a Pod causing it to be terminated, the container runtime will get notified of the state update and a `SIGTERM` will be sent to all container pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When initiating a pod deletion request

```
kubectl delete pods <POD>
```

the container runtime would send a `TERM` signal **to the main process in each container**.

When the `--force --grace-period=0` switch options are used, the container runtime will send a `TERM` followed directly by the `KILL` signal.

`kubectl` won't initiate a termination request in a container based fashion but would rather terminate all containers running inside a terminated pod.

Note that a pod won't transition to a `TERMINATING` state only upon an explicit request to delete the latter, but this should be a core part of how *Kubernetes* would manage your cluster meaning that it might terminate a **perfectly healthy** container for one of below reasons:

- If the deployment is updated with a rolling update
- If a node is drained
- If a node runs out of resources

You can check [the *Pods Lifecycle* documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) for further details.

Comment: When the `--force --grace-period=0` option is not used with `kubectl` command, is `SIGKILL` not sent?

Comment: Yes, I do think so. Even though there is not similar statement in the official documentation, but based on my experience, you should rely on the `SIGTERM` signal as it gets sent upon termination no-matter is the initiating event and the used arguments. Meanwhile, even if the `SIGKILL` signal gets sent, you will have little chance to operate your shutdown work as the *Kubernetes* manager will leave you with little (if not at all) time window.